# Is it possible to launch a console app from an Office Add-In (C#)

Tags: c#, console, vsto

I think the subject says it all, I'm trying to open a console (really just for debugging, to write object properties) from an Outlook Addin I wrote in C#.  If so, how would you go about it? I tried starting a new console project just to see how it did it, but can't really see an easy way about it.

any thoughts are much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is correct in your Outlook addin cant you have some code like

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
```

The above code is to invoke the appropriate file for opening. If the file name is of an exe then i guess it should open your console app.

UPDATE: 
You can include an console app that has the Main method as follows:

```
static void Main(string args[])
{
     Console.Write(args[0].ToString());
     Console.Read();
}
```

And now in your Load method of the outlook addin :

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename, "hello test");
}
```

Now when your addin loads the console app should fire up and then print "hello test" in the console.

Comment: ah - I may have been slightly unclear.  I was basically hoping to open a console window from the addin, not a seperate application. By opening that console window, I was hoping to Console.Write(AddIn code results), if that makes sense.

Comment: Oh.. so if that is the case just include an empty console app in your addin and when you want to debug just open this along with some arguments that would print it out to the console in your Main method by reading the args. This might a simple solution.

Comment: Thanks - how would I launch that console app? I've added a console app project to my add-in, added a reference to it in my main adding project, and added this code, but basically nothing happens...:
            DebugConsole.Program test = new Program();
            
            Console.WriteLine("TEST");
            Console.Read();

Comment: You would need to call that command. In your outlook addin during the load method call that line of code

Comment: Thats currently where it is...
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {// Create reference to console application
            DebugConsole.Program test = new Program();
            
            Console.WriteLine("TEST");
            Console.Read();

           ...

Comment: I guess you need to have Process.Start("yourconsoleappnamehere") instead of the above code.